# MatLab creating an array of 999x1 first 333 are 1 next 333 are 2 last 333 are 3

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create an array of values for error checking I have beautifully implemented a baysian classifier but cannot seem to create a 1x999 array.

I think it is clear what I want from the code I currently have

```
zEst = [1:999]; % Supposed to be an initalization
for i=1:N
    if(i < 334)
        xEst(i) = 1;
    elseif(i < 667)
        xEst(i) = 2;
    else
        xEst(i) = 3;
    end
end
```

Is there a way to do this nicely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possible approaches:

1. With `ceil`:

   ```
   m = 999;
   n = 3;
   xEst = ceil((n/m:n/m:n));
   ```
2. With `repmat`:

   ```
   xEst = reshape(repmat([1:n], m, 1), 1, []);
   ```
3. With `kron`:

   ```
   xEst = kron(1:n, ones(1,m));
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
xEst = ones(999, 1);
xEst(334 : 666) = 2;
xEst(667 : end) = 3;
```